# How to get selected option id in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipleselection

I have one select field and am passing selected option value to the client script.

```html
<div>
    <select class="custom-select" multiple id='select-user' ng-model='SelectedOptions'>
        <option ng-repeat='app in data.arr track by $index' value={{app.name}} id={{app.id}}>{{app.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <button ng-click='selectedServers(SelectedOptions)' class='rightBtn'><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.selectedServers = function (options) {
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        $scope.datas.push(options[i]);
    }
    console.log($scope.datas)//getting only option value
}
```

Here I need to get `id` of selected option as well and push into the array `$scope.datas` along with option value.

How can I pass the selected option id with value?

Comment: Hello, if your issue was resolved by the below answer, consider marking as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` with `as-for-in` syntax:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data= [{
      name: 'opt1',
      id: 'id1'
    }, {
      name: 'opt2',
      id: 'id2'
    }, {
      name: 'opt3',
      id: 'id3'
    }];
    
    
    $scope.selectedServers = function() {      
      // Here you have the selected options with both name and id
      console.log($scope.selected);
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select class="custom-select" multiple id='select-user' ng-model="selected" ng-options='s as s.name for s in data'>
  </select>

  <button ng-click='selectedServers()' class='rightBtn'><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Get options</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @krish I changed the variable names to make it simpler